# Hyperlink within same report - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, hyperlink

Report ABC has three tabs 1, 2, 3. Tab 3 is graph view. I want to create a hyperlink on tab 3 to link it to tab 1 on the same report. So when I click on a particular cell in Tab 3, it takes me to tab 1. How do I do it?

Comment: Tabs? Which control has tabs in reporting-services?

Comment: By tabs i meant the worksheets in the excel output

Comment: Have a look into Bookmark Action, not sure if it fits your porpuse. Can't try it myself right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you can create them so that they work in the report manager but I have not tried them in excel.

[Here](https://blogs.infosupport.com/creating-tabs-in-ssrs/) is a guide on how to create them for the report manager.